# Center span inside a div container over an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have images that are responsive in size and I'm trying to overlay a play icon in the center of them. I'm able to center the icon vertically but not horizontally.

See my [jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/f1becapq/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/503897818_640.jpg" style="width:315px;height:177px;">
  <div class="post-video-overlay-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-video-overlay-lg {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  width:315px;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: you mean [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/f1becapq/2/)

Comment: @jbutler483 That's close but if I change the height of my image to 277px the icon is no longer centered...

Comment: you mean the image? Or the glyphicon?

Comment: Sorry, the glyphicon

Comment: Use the calc css for something like that (if glyphicon changes height) [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/f1becapq/5/). But just a point of note; those vendor prefixes on the border radius aren't actually needed anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you have to position the overlay div over the image/video..then position the span.

```css
.post-video-overlay-lg {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #E5E5E5;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.post-video-overlay-lg span {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width:315px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.img-container img {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/503897818_640.jpg" style="width:315px;height:177px;" />
    <div class="post-video-overlay-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f1becapq/6/)

Comment: The bootstrap css isn't linked that's why - Added fiddle link.

Comment: @Paulie_D: You also left in the prefixed border-radius properties, and i'm lead to believe these are no longer required. But that's a whole different kettle of fish! :P

Comment: @jbutler483...I'm using the OPs code...I'll only adjust what is required to fix the original issue...but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f1becapq/3/

Updated the css for `.post-video-overlay-lg`

```
.post-video-overlay-lg {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: #E5E5E5;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -webkit-calc(50% - 36px);    /* 36px = 72px/2 */
    top: -moz-calc(50% - 36px);
    top: calc(50% - 36px);
}
```

Used the CSS `calc` function to vertically align the div in runtime